# Identify and replace rows in a ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894000/replace-subarrays-in-numpy) question except I have a stricter condition:  I need to replace a occurrences of an entire row and not just values that may exist elsewhere in the column.  The line #368 should give an idea of how many fancy-indexed experiments have thus far failed:

```
In [368]:

a=np.array([[[ 42.30803907,   0.        ,   0.        ],
        [ 42.30803907,   3.0052592 ,   0.        ]],

       [[ 42.30803907,   3.0052592 ,   0.        ],
        [ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   0.        ]],

       [[ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   0.        ],
        [ 42.14713681,   8.84169967,   0.        ]]])
In [369]:

toBeReplaced=np.array([ 42.30803907,   3.0052592 ,   0.        ])
In [370]:

b=a==toBeReplaced
#b returns:
#array([[[ True, False,  True],
#        [ True,  True,  True]],
#
#       [[ True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False,  True]],
#
#       [[False, False,  True],
#        [False, False,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

And here's where I can't seem to get the condition syntax right:

```
a=np.where(b==[True,True,True], [9,9,9], a)

Out[373]:
array([[[  9.        ,   0.        ,   9.        ],
        [  9.        ,   9.        ,   9.        ]],

       [[  9.        ,   9.        ,   9.        ],
        [ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   9.        ]],

       [[ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   9.        ],
        [ 42.14713681,   8.84169967,   9.        ]]])
```

You can see that the boolean mask replaces all occurrences on a column basis.  Is there a way to alter the Boolean mask or the array on which it is used as a selector so that only rows whose value in all three columns matches the columns of the search array?

(N.B. I should also note that although my data is float64, all the "matching" occurrences I'm looking for return True on np.all() as they are the same underlying computed value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mask identifying where the condition is satisfied in all the columns:

```
mask = np.all(a==[42.30803907, 3.0052592, 0.], axis=2)
a[mask] = [9, 9, 9]

#array([[[ 42.30803907,   0.        ,   0.        ],
#        [  9.        ,   9.        ,   9.        ]],
# 
#       [[  9.        ,   9.        ,   9.        ],
#        [ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   0.        ]],
# 
#       [[ 40.54907736,   5.44198582,   0.        ],
#        [ 42.14713681,   8.84169967,   0.        ]]])
```