# How to use np.where on 3D array with all()

Tags: python, numpy

I've been stuck for quite some time on this problem.

I have an array of shape (4,3,3). In my real case, the shape is much bigger.

```
a = np.array([
    [[1,2,3], [3,4,2], [1,3,4]],
    [[1,2,3], [3,6,2], [1,4,4]],
    [[1,2,3], [3,6,2], [1,4,4]],
    [[1,2,3], [3,6,2], [1,2,4]]
])
```

I want to use the `np.where` function to replace some of the list inside the array.
For example, each time I have the list `[1,2,3]`, I want to replace it by the list `[99,99,99]`.

Without using `np.where`, to check if the list is completely equal to `[1,2,3]`, I would use some function like `all()`.

Using `np.where`:

```
np.where(a == [1,2,3], 99, a)
```

Will result in:

```
array([[[99, 99, 99],
    [ 3,  4,  2],
    [99,  3,  4]],

   [[99, 99, 99],
    [ 3,  6,  2],
    [99,  4,  4]],

   [[99, 99, 99],
    [ 3,  6,  2],
    [99,  4,  4]],

   [[99, 99, 99],
    [ 3,  6,  2],
    [99, 99,  4]]])
```

As you can see on the 3rd row, a part of the list has been replaced by 99.

I only want to replace the full list (never a part of the list) when it's exactly `[1,2,3]` and in the right order.

But I cannot solve this problem. I've been looking a lot online, with no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write (4,3,3). I will edit. Please don't thumbdown because of that.

Comment: `a[(a == [1,2,3]).all(-1)] = 99`, IIUC. Please include your desired result.

Comment: Is this for an assignment? The "***Without using np.where, ..., i would use some function like all().*** is very peculiar phrasing ^^

Comment: @mozway - I didn't see that part.

Comment: I'm not native speaker ahah I'm trying my best

Comment: @michael Is there an easy solution without using all() ? I'm interested in.

Comment: @Marie `np.where` works at the element level. I think you have to use `.all()` at some point to tell np to look at a whole row, now just a single element. @Michael's solution is very elegant imho. It doesn't get much more concise than that!

Comment: @joanis Sorry I didn't see the answer. With all the edited comments, deleted comments and stuff I got lost. I will examinate the answer.

Comment: It looks like exactly what I've been looking for, thank you very much for your time @michael. You saved my day ahah. I hope other people could benefit from your answer too. It can be use to replace a color (RGB) by another color in a image.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Could you turn your comment into an answer? This would save time for people people looking for unanswered questions and it makes the answer more visible for people coming to this page via search engines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify and replace rows in a ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587281/identify-and-replace-rows-in-a-ndarray)

Comment: Or with [solutions with `np.where`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894000/replace-subarrays-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

The `cond` array is central to the workings of `where`:

```
In [167]: a == [1, 2, 3]
Out[167]: 
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False]]])
```

You get `99` everywhere there's a `True`. We can use `all` to identify rows:

```
In [168]: (a == [1, 2, 3]).all(axis=-1)
Out[168]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

But we can't use that in the where because it is 2d, and `a` is 3d:

```
In [169]: np.where(_, 99, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [169] in <module>
    np.where(_, 99, a)
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in where
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) () (4,3,3)
```

But we can adjust the shape of the `cond` so it works:

```
In [171]: np.where(Out[168][...,None], 99, a)
Out[171]: 
array([[[99, 99, 99],
        [ 3,  4,  2],
        [ 1,  3,  4]],

       [[99, 99, 99],
        [ 3,  6,  2],
        [ 1,  4,  4]],

       [[99, 99, 99],
        [ 3,  6,  2],
        [ 1,  4,  4]],

       [[99, 99, 99],
        [ 3,  6,  2],
        [ 1,  2,  4]]])
```

Michael Szczesny's suggestion also works, because the 2d mask selects the desired rows from `a`:

```
In [172]: a[Out[168]]
Out[172]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```